# How to expand t.co URLs in tweets with python

Tags: python, api, twitter

I wrote program in python that extract links that are in tweets and that are in t.co/xxxxx format i want to convert links to unshorten format i use below code

```
tmep= urlopen(url)  
full_url=temp.geturl()
```

but it isn't fast and because want to open page use much bandwidth and most of time it return erros.I cant't find any API from twitter that can expand url.anybody have solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the `expanded_url` from the Tweet object instead of the `url` - that will automatically give you the full URL.